# How to add normals to an existing point cloud with open3d?

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, open3d

I have a point cloud .ply file that I have opened with open3d. I also have normals in a numpy array. I want to add these normals to my point cloud. I do not want to "Estimate" normals, I only want to add already existing normals to my point cloud.

Comment: Have you tried modifying field `.normals` of your point cloud object? See the documentation at [open3d.geometry.PointCloud.normals](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html?highlight=normals#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.normals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify `.normals` attribute with a *numpy* array directly. You need to use `o3d.utility.Vector3dVector` wrapper.

Example:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

cloud: o3d.geometry.PointCloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(r"...")

normals = np.zeros_like(np.asarray(cloud.points))
cloud.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(normals)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I had another question if you could help with it too. So I created an animation with "o3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_animation_callback" and I was hoping if I could somehow save this animation as gif or any video format. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't know. Ask it as a separate question, so other might find and answer it.